# Getting error while running an existing modflow model using flopy package

Tags: python, flopy

I am using flopy package to change the content of well package and then to run the model and finally get all output heads. I have loaded my model successfully and I have changed the content of well package but when it comes to running the model after all these changes I've got this error. You know, there is no file named .name file in the file of my model but instead I have used ".mfn" file which can be considered as an alternative for ".name" file in my model. I don't know how can I solve this problem.
Thanks in advance for your answers.
**Here is my written code:**

```
import flopy
import os
import sys
first = flopy.modflow.Modflow.load("step6.mfn", version='mf2k',exe_name=mf2k.exe", verbose =True , model_ws = "step6._ws" , load_only=None , forgive=False , check =False )
success, buff = first.run_model()
if not success:
    raise Exception("MODFLOW did not terminate normally.")
```

**And here is the error:**

```
----> 5 success, buff = first.run_model()
      6 if not success:
      7     raise Exception("MODFLOW did not terminate normally.")

File C:\Python27\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flopy\mbase.py:1361, in BaseModel.run_model(self, silent, pause, report, normal_msg)
   1330 def run_model(
   1331     self,
   1332     silent=False,
   (...)
   1335     normal_msg="normal termination",
   1336 ):
   1337     """
   1338     This method will run the model using subprocess.Popen.
   1339 
   (...)
   1358 
   1359     """
-> 1361     return run_model(
   1362         self.exe_name,
   1363         self.namefile,
   1364         model_ws=self.model_ws,
   1365         silent=silent,
   1366         pause=pause,
   1367         report=report,
   1368         normal_msg=normal_msg,
   1369     )

File C:\Python27\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flopy\mbase.py:1708, in run_model(exe_name, namefile, model_ws, silent, pause, report, normal_msg, use_async, cargs)
   1706 if namefile is not None:
   1707     if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(model_ws, namefile)):
-> 1708         raise Exception(
   1709             f"The namefile for this model does not exists: {namefile}"
   1710         )
   1712 # simple little function for the thread to target
   1713 def q_output(output, q):

Exception: The namefile for this model does not exists: step6.nam
```

Comment: Hello, is there a reason why you're using Python 2.7?

Comment: Change  exe_name=mf2k.exe" you need to change to exe_name="mf2k.exe"